# Page style not being reflected on actual print using Impact/Dot Matrix printer

Tags: javascript, css, printing, dot-matrix

I have a web page that triggers a javascript print function, the browser's print preview shows up properly with the design, however when I hit on Print, the resulting page printed is different from the actual style.

The printer is an Impact/Dot Matrix printer model (Epson LX-300 II impact printer)

I have tried to change the CSS font-family to different values but it does not change. Changing the size does reflect on print.

Answer (score 0):

You must take the advantage of Media queries and,you must write your stylesheet for printing,
using this code

```
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #header, #footer, #nav { display: none !important; } 
}
```

To learn more
Please visit:

[CSS Mediatypes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)
[CSS Tricks Tutorial on Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)